# Salesforce SSO appending user id to the user name

Tags: force.com, single-sign-on

I'm trying to setup sp initiated SSO with salesforce as the iDP.

The service is expecting the username to be in the response but salesforce is sending the org id appended to the user name so instead of myuser@username.com it's sending [organizationid]@myuser@username.com.

How can I get it to stop sending the userid? It should just be sending the username

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you have *Subject Type* in your Service Provider's SAML, configured as *Username* in Salesforce. If that's the case, then what you are experiencing is the *expected behavior*.

From [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=identity_provider_portals_sites.htm&type=5):

> When defining a service provider, if the Subject Type is *Username*, the *Salesforce organization ID is prepended to the user name in the SAML assertion*. For example, if the user is *jDeoint@WFC.com*, the subject for the SAML assertion contains *00DE0000000FFLT@jDeoint@WFC.com*.
>
> If the Subject Type is Federation ID, the exact federation ID is used.

If you don't want this to be returned in your SAML response, you should change the *Subject Type* to one of the available options. To view the available options, refer to [Defining Service Providers as SAML-Enabled Connected Apps](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=service_provider_define.htm&type=5).

> Subject Type
>
> Specifies which field defines the user’s identity for the app. Options include the user’s username, federation ID, user ID, a custom attribute, or an algorithmically calculated persistent ID. A custom attribute can be any custom field added to the User object in the organization, as long as it is one of the following data types: Email, Text, URL, or Formula (with Text Return Type). After you select Custom Attribute for the Subject Type, Salesforce displays a Custom Attribute field with a list of the available User object custom fields in the organization.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up creating a formula field that just copies the username and used the new field which prevented the org id from being appended